# how to adjust 'ToolSettings.proportional_edit_falloff' in the user interface?

Tags: modeling

Sorry, total newbie here. Trying to follow Blender guru's make a donut tutorial.
Trying to move just a few vertices on either side by dragging a single node.But turning on smoothing affects too large an area. There is no circle of focus for smoothing regardless of zoom position. Answers given on the video page don't have an effect. F1 help gives a error msg:

No reference available 'ToolSettings.proportional_edit_falloff', Update info in 'rna_manual_reference.py' or callback to bpy.utils.manual_map()

using blender 2.83.12 on  Mac Air, using an apple mouse (virtual buttons and wheel).

Thanks for any help in advance

Comment: Have you tried using your scroll wheel? If all vertices move together with the one selected, perhaps the circle of influence (not sure how it's called) is so big it's not within your view. Try scrolling the mouse wheel up for a while.

Comment: Using an apple mouse - no scroll wheel, 'scrolling' gives me zoom,pan or rotate with cmd & shift keys. What is you default wheel action when selecting a node?

Comment: Switched mouse to one with a wheel. focus now works. Yea!!

Answer (score 0):

Apple mouse does not have scroll wheel. virtual scrolling defaults to rotate and does not allow focus adjustment. Using 3 button mouse with wheel works fine and solves this problem.
Perhaps a developer knows a work around for the apple mouse.
Thanks to Markus von Broady for the tip.
.....
Reattached apple mouse, now the circle appears after the 'G' command. Scrolling the mouse wheel down to bring the focus into range (on screen)
was the correct action it appears. Sigh.